# PHP CSV import getting strange charators

Tags: php, mysql, fgetcsv, csv-import

I'm trying to import a product csv using `PHP to MySQL`. When i try to import I got strange characters which also not add properly to `database table`.

```
Product Name on CSV File
```

**Alva Cook'on Braadpan Lavendelblauw ovaal 24 cm – 4,2 Liter**

Product name i got when import function execute

**Alva Cook'on Braadpan Lavendelblauw ovaal 24 cm â€“ 4,2 Liter**

my code is like

```
while (($emapData = fgetcsv($filepath, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
{
    $pd_name=  ($emapData[1]);
}
```

i used this function as a solution this shows product name correctly on import page

```
$pd_name=mb_convert_encoding(($emapData[1]), 'UCS-2LE', 'UTF-8');

Output ~ Alva Cook'on Braadpan Lavendelblauw ovaal 24 cm – 4,2 Liter
```

But when i use `mysql_real_escape_string` as below for insert the name to db table, it added lots of `slashes` and not work properly.

```
$pd_name=mysql_real_escape_string(mb_convert_encoding(($emapData[1]), 'UCS-2LE', 'UTF-8'));


Output ~ A\0l\0v\0a\0 \0C\0o\0o\0k\0\'\0o\0n\0 \0B\0r\0a\0a\0d\0p\0a\0n\0 \0L\0a\0v\0e\0n\0d\0e\0l\0b\0l\0a\0u\0w\0 \0o\0v\0a\0a\0l\0 \02\04\0 \0c\0m\0 \0 \04\0,\02\0 \0L\0i\0t\0e\0r\0
```

`SQL database` table supports `UTF` and when we add products normally using form we don't face this problem, anyone know how to fix this issue. Thank You

Comment: use utf8_encode(); hope it will work

Comment: You need to use the same charset throughout your ENTIRE rendering chain. PHP itself doesn't about the charset of a string. A string is a string, containing a bunch of bytes. What those bytes represent is irrelevant to PHP Itself. It's when you start processing that string that the actual representation matters. If you convert to utf-8 as you're doing, but you haven't told the output/display environment to expect UTF, then you will get "mangled" characters.

Comment: @KamleshGupta it doesn't work mate

Comment: @abra I'm not sure why this is duplicate, becoz i can show the output on site correctly but i cannot save this using my sql, that question doesn't have correct answer

Comment: @MarcB do you know any alternative for mysql_real_escape_string(mb_convert_encoding(($emapData[1]), 'UCS-2LE', 'UTF-8')); please, becoz without mysql_real_escape_string it works good but i need to add mysql_real_escape_string for escape ' chars

Comment: actually in your string contain some garbage character which is not support sql server...if you remove or replace with space so may be it work

Comment: – seems have issue i'll try to use - instead of that

Comment: it worked after reverse functions $pd_name=mb_convert_encoding(mysql_real_escape_string($emapData[1]), 'UCS-2LE', 'UTF-8');

also the long dash  –  sign was a garbage character, we used - instead of that. other other lathin and German characters worked fine after above fix, hope this comment helpful for someone since i cannot post this as an answer because question marked as duplicated

Answer (score -1):

You should start with the fact that the function `mysql_real_escape_string` has been deprecated:

> Warning
>   This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
>   mysqli_real_escape_string()
>   PDO::quote()

Then you should use `mysqli_real_escape string` in combination with `mysqli_set_charset`

## Oficial PHP Documentation:

- [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)
- [mysqli_set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php)

Comment: Site have hundreds of mysql functions. so I'm don't have time to find and convert those all to mysqli, we will consider about later, anyway will this solve issue ?